# Prevent elements moving in php document -

Tags: php, html, css

Currently experiencing a slight issue with a cart I'm building -

What it should look like :-
[image]

What happens when I resize : -
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have attached the necessary file(s) below :)

index.php
https://hastebin.com/otuzowuwir.xml

css/style.css
https://hastebin.com/vapunugeka.css

Comment: is this xml file multiple pages or just one ? im asking because you have multiple <head>, <body> and <html> tags that are all over the place

Comment: I'm very new, using an abundance of videos to try teach my along the way. I simply can get everything working, but whenever I seem to resize the page 99% of the time it always breaks - as seen in screenshot. I need to learn how to fix this, it's always a concern.

Comment: nothing wrong with that, just trying to figure out whats happening in that file

Comment: My knowledge is very limited. I usually just try for hours and eventually get it, leaving the code a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have more than 1 head, body and html tag in your page.
To help you with your code you should use an IDE. W3C is also a great tool to check for errors https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thank you for this, I will ensure I will use this as a reference.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion(s) to fix my current issue, I am pretty lost.

Comment: Well first your document should start with <html> and end with </html>.
Then just after <html> you have your head tag <head>...</head> and after that you have the <body> tag. Put all you template inside the body tag.
Also all meta, title and links tags should be inside your head tag

Comment: Alright, and making an element have a fixed position?

Comment: Thus not moving w/ the browser.

Comment: You should have a clean code before trying to solve your issue. Once it's done show me your code again.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot, I'll keep you updated thank you once again.

Comment: to fix your problems i would do it like this: 1. remove all <?php> stuff from the file, 2. use the html validator to check your html and fix the many problems, 3. choose on version of bootstrap and dont run multiple at the same time.

Comment: Okay, I will watch some youtube videos, as my knowledge is very limited. I think I need to get a teacher as well - so they can fix my issues and possibly even write side notes on the doc.

Comment: I am stuck. Can anybody help I have abundance of issues and don't understand, I'm sorry.